# Does a bottle route for /something also handle /something/else?

Tags: python, bottle

I have a [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) site that loads content via `getJSON()` requests.

To handle normal requests made when navigating the site, `getJSON()` requests are made to a Python script which dumps the results in JSON format.

Push/pop state is used to change the URL when the dynamic content is loaded.

To handle this same dynamic content when directly accessing the URL, eg reloading the page, I create a conditional which loads the bottle template and passes the path to the `getJSON()` request, which then loads the dynamic content.

```
@route('/')
@route('/<identifier>')
def my_function(identifier='index'):
    # do things with certain paths using if and elif conditionals
    #
    # handle the getJSON() path
    elif value_passed_to_getJSON.startswith("part_one/"):
        # get the path after / , in this example it should be 'part_two'
        my_variable = value_passed_to_getJSON.split("/")[1]
        # perform database query with my_variable
        response.content_type = 'application/json'
        return dumps(cursor)

# and later for direct URL access, eg reloading the page, this essentially routes the query
# back to the getJSON() path handler above.  

    elif identifier == "part_one/part_two":
        return template('site_template',value_passed_to_getJSON="/" + identifier)
```

This setup is working when the identifier is something like `part_one` but not in the format above ie `part_one/part_two`, in that case a 404 is raised.

As another test, if I simply put:

```
    elif identifier == "part_one/part_two":
        return "hello"
```

I also get a 404 with a Firebug error on `GET part_two`.

I am wondering if this is because the initial route `@route('/<identifier>')` only contains a single value and forward slash?

Does it need an extra wildcard to handle the two parts of the path?

**Demonstrated Solution** (per comment below)

```
@route('/')
@route('/<identifier:path>')
@view('my_template.tpl')
def index(identifier='index'):

if identifier == 'part_one/part_two':
    return "hello"
else:
    return "something standard"
```

Comment: Change `<identifier>` to `<identifier:path>` and it should match those URLs.

Comment: You are a god among men, thank you, that worked - example implementation added to original post.

Comment: For reference, the above solution seemed to conflict with `@route('/change_password/:reset_code')`, the solution to this was to place it above `@route('/') @route('/<identifier:path>')`.